# ¿Abrir outlook desde php con correo predefinido?

Tags: php

Saludos esto lo encontré por aquí mismo, pero no me funciona me pregunto si me falta agregar una extensión o algo para que funcione, lo que quiero es abrir outlook desde php con un correo y tengo este código:

Aquí encontré el código:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507339/open-outlook-using-php-on-client-machine

```
<?php
    com_load_typelib('Outlook.Application');
    $objApp = new COM("Outlook.Application") or die ( "Cannot Load Outlook.Application" ); 

    $namespace = $objApp->GetNamespace("MAPI");  // or MAPI.Session
    $namespace->Logon(); 
    $myItem = $objApp->CreateItem ( olMailItem );   
    $myItem->To = $div_wise_value['emails'];
    $myItem->Subject = "Mail subject"; 
    $myItem->HTMLBody = "mail body";
    $myItem->Display();
?>
```

El error que me presenta es este:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function com_load_typelib() in

Comment: Estaría genial que añadieses varias cosas a tu pregunta: 1) el enlace de dónde lo sacaste. 2) Una aclaración de qué es lo que pasa, "no me funciona" no es muy descriptivo. 3) Esto más que añadir es que te leas esto-> [ask] y que le eches un ojo al [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos. Bienvenido.

Comment: _No me funciona_ no nos dice mucho :/

Comment: indica cual es el error que sale por pantalla o hasta donde has llegado que te sale por pantalla, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Falta agregar la extensión que tiene esas funciones
COM_DOT_NET

```
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Al final de **`php.ini`**.